# Como implementar Service Layer com Spring?

Tags: java, aplicação-web, spring, services

Alguém conhece algum tutorial, exemplos... alguma fonte para aprender a implementar camada de serviço?

Comment: Veja se lhe ajuda  [este link](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=camada+de+servi%C3%A7os+web+spring+services&oq=camada+de+servi%C3%A7os+web+spring+services&aqs=chrome..69i57.5436j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=camada+de+servi%C3%A7os+web+spring+services+tutorial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A camada de serviço é onde vai ter todas suas regras de negocio antes da persistencia e claro onde vai controlar a transação do banco de dados.

```
//declare aqui a anotação service
@Service
public class MyService {

      ...
}
```

Para controle de transação use o @Transactional(readOnly = true)
por padrão o spring já configura o transançao pra só da commit quando tudo der certo no seu metodo.

Você pode alterar isso com :

```
 @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,readOnly=false) 
    public void save(ProductTech product) { 
        currentSession().save(product); 
        System.out.println(“product saved with sucess”); 
    }
```

**PROPAGATION_MANDATORY**: Obriga o uso de uma transação, caso não haja nenhuma transação corrente, é lançada uma exceção.

**PROPAGATION_NESTED**: Executa dentro de uma transação aninhada se uma transação corrente existir.

**PROPAGATION_NEVER**: Impede o uso de uma transação. Caso exista uma transação corrente, é lançada uma exceção.

**PROPAGATION_NOT_SUPPORTED**: Não usa a transação corrente. Este é executado sempre sem nenhuma transação.

**PROPAGATION_REQUIRED**: Usa a transação corrente se existir, caso não exista cria uma nova transação.

**PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW**: Cria uma nova transação, se já existir uma corrente, suspende esta.

**PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS**: Usa a transação corrente se existir, caso contrário executa sem transação.

**Pronto depois disso basta injetar o seu Serviço no seu Controlador**

Comment: Vi que é possível manter o Dao com as operações no banco e o service para a lógica de negócio. Para usar minha classe service eu apenas anoto com @service e injeto ela no controller e chamos o métodos que criei? Tem alguma convenção no nome dos métodos? Quantas classes de service precisa ter para manter a coesão?

Comment: @MatheusSilva Se você precisa de mais detalhes, edite sua pergunta ou faça novas perguntas mais específicas. Comentários não são adequados para ficar adicionando conteúdo. Além disso considere que suas novas perguntas podem ser muito amplas ou baseadas em opiniões, pois existem muitas convenções e a quantidade de classes é algo que depende muito do sistema em questão. Sugiro que leia sobre [ask]. Abraco!

Comment: @MatheusSilva se tirou sua dúvida marca como respondida por favor